# Delay in between two calls (POST and GET) in Google Apps script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, get, urlfetch

My first request on StackOverflow!  I really hope you can help me!

I want to create a process to automatize a data report from a system to a sheet; I thought I could use their API, apps script, and export the data on google sheets.
To do so, I need to run two calls on the API:

1. A POST call, which runs the report within the system (it requires a date range as body).
   In return, I will get an ID that is associated with the data generated and it expires after some time.
2. A GET call, which is a URL that contains the ID generated in the first call and created with a concatenation.

The first call works fine; I get in return the ID successfully.

My problem is when I run the second call, I don’t get any data in return, and I don’t understand what’s the issue, I can see the URL is concatenated correctly because if I copy the URL from the log and I test it on another apps script or on Postman, it works perfectly fine!
Could someone help me in case I am doing something wrong?
Here’s the code:

```
    function callEvents() {
      var API_KEY = "xxx";
      var data = { 'Start Date': '2021-05-03', 'End Date': '2021-06-03' }
      var options = {
        'method' : 'post',
      'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(data) };
    //This is the first call
       var urlEncoded = encodeURI('https://website/api/dataviewresult/
                 etc/json/?api_key=' + API_KEY);
       var url = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlEncoded, options);
      var result = JSON.parse(url.getContentText());
     Logger.log(url.getContentText());
    //here I retrieve the ID to use in the second call
    var ipdataview = (result["contents"]["id"]);
      Logger.log(ipdataview);

//here is the concatenation and the second call
      var urlEncoded2 = encodeURI('https://website/api/dataviewresult/etc/json/'+ipdataview+'/?api_key=' + API_KEY);
        Logger.log(urlEncoded2);
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urlEncoded2);
        Logger.log(response.getContentText());
```

Comment: It seems that in your script, 3 requests are run. Can I ask you about the detail of your script? And, can I ask you about the detail of your goal? And also, can you provide the official document of the methods of API you want to use?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, exactly, the third request is just a testing of the second one with the URL paste it in full, rather than built with the combination of KEY API and ID data view from the first request. I just left it to understand why the third request works fine but the second one which has the same URL doesn't return any data back.
My final goal is to retrieve data from an external system for events planning and reporting the list of events into a google sheet. The method I want to use it's mentioned here [link](https://manual.yesplan.be/en/developers/dataviews/#retrieve-dataview-result).

Comment: Can you explain what is the issue then, I understand that the first call is to get the data you need to make the call and then calls 2 and 3 are the same, but 2 is not working. But why is not alright to use function 3 if it works?

Comment: I need to create a GET Url that contains the id of the data report returned from the first call (POST). I don't understand why my coding to create the URL with the report ID and the Key API doesn't work, as I don't get any data back in the second call. The third call works but it's the same URL generated in the second call, I simply copy and paste it . Ideally I would like this to be automatize

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that your 3rd request works fine and your 2nd request doesn't work. I cannot understand about your 1st request. I apologize for this. And I cannot image about `My final goal is to retrieve data from an external system for events planning and reporting the list of events into a google sheet.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike, I edited my question above (I wrote it in rush and realize now how poorly was made), so hopefully, it should be clear now. I think my issue is in the way I concatenate the URL in the second call, can you help me, please?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `My problem is when I run the second call, I don’t get any data in return`, can I ask you about the detail of it? Because I cannot test your request. By this, I cannot understand about whether an error occurs and whether `I don’t get any data in return` means that the empty values are returned. I apologize for this.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, No need to apologize, thank you for your help!
So after I run the second  call, I use this command Logger.log(response.getContentText()), to view the data in the log, but it's empty, no error is generated.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `So after I run the second call, I use this command Logger.log(response.getContentText()), to view the data in the log, but it's empty, no error is generated`, in your situation, no error occurs and the empty value is returned. In this case, although I'm not sure about the API you want to use, is it considered that the request works fine and the returned value for the endpoint is empty?

Comment: No, I'm sure there's data, as I said if I copy the URL combined for the second call and paste it into a new call I get the data in return without issue. So maybe my error is in how I combined the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution, I was doing the second call (Get) too soon from the first one, so the data was not being picked up.

I used utilities.sleep() for about 2 seconds and it worked perfectly.

Thank you for everyone helping!
S